# What's the best way to delete specific characters in a JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, database, element

Currently, I have a huge JavaScript array where each element is like this:

```
[{"open":235.86,
  "high":247.13,
  "low":231.5,
  "close":244.1,
  "volume":55025735,
  "date":"2019-05-01T21:00:00.000Z"}
  ...
```

I need to remove everything except the price after high. What is the most efficient way I can do this?

I've tried popping the individual elements, but I can't help but feel as if there is a more efficient/easier way to do this.

So hopefully the ending array would just be `[235.86]`.

Comment: This is JSON object, the end result couldn't end it being just `235.86`, it would have to be `[ {"open": 235.86 } ]`

Comment: Consider the opposite approach and extract what you want into a new Object/Array

Comment: [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: I'm working on an answer right now :)

Comment: @baranskistad why couldn't you extract the value of one JSON field and stick it in an array?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code should work. It's efficient enough :D

```
for (i in arrayName){
   // Loops through array
   delete arrayName[i].high
   delete arrayName[i].low
   delete arrayName[i].close
   delete arrayName[i].volume
   delete arrayName[i].date
   // Deletes unwanted properties
}
console.log(arrayName)
// Print output
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` for this scenario. Example

```
var temp = [{"open":235.86, "high":247.13, "low":231.5, "close":244.1, "volume":55025735, "date":"2019-05-01T21:00:00.000Z"}];
var highValArray = temp.reduce((arr, t) => {
    return arr.concat(t['high']);
}, []);
```

You can learn more about reduce function at the [MDN website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

Comment: Can you provide a link to `reduce` (documentation)? Not here in comments, but by [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55962056/edit).

Answer (score 0):

One potential solution would be to map the array to a new array like so:

```
const yourArray = [
  {"open":235.86, "high":247.13, "low":231.5, "close":244.1, "volume":55025735},
  {"open":257.52, "high":234.53, "low":220.2, "close":274.1, "volume":23534060},
]
const mappedArray = yourArray.map(el => el.open);
// mappedArray = [235.86, 257.52]
```

Check out the MDN documentation for the map method, [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

**Note**: The above example uses ECMAScript 6 arrow functions and implicit returns. It is functionally equivalent to:

```
const yourArray = [
  {"open":235.86, "high":247.13, "low":231.5, "close":244.1, "volume":55025735},
  {"open":257.52, "high":234.53, "low":220.2, "close":274.1, "volume":23534060},
]
const mappedArray = yourArray.map(function(el){
  return el.open
});
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
your_array.map((item) => {
  return item.high
})
```

Comment: this is a section to provide answers, not questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: It is better not to answer as a rhetorical question. [This is not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115). If you want to solicit a response, do it in comments to your answer (or perhaps in comments to the question). Also, it would be better to provide an explanation along with the code.